# Send post with curl php

Tags: php, http, post, curl, request

I'm trying to send some parameters for an autentication on a web page this is the code

```
$url = "http://www.webpage.com/account/submit";
$handler = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=user@webmail.com&remember=true&password=123456");
$response = curl_exec ($handler);
curl_close($handler);
```

When I run this script shows nothing, Im trying to autenticate me succesfully into a website without the HTML form . . .  there is another way to do this ???

Comment: Are you even printing the response?

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse it shows nothing. You would at least have to [`echo`](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) something (and likely do something with `$response` to actually check the result of the login). Also, make sure [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is enabled.

Comment: What I really mean with this is . . . when I enter into the web page login there is no session created, thats what I actually want. Do you know if there is something wrong with the code ???

Comment: do a curl_getinfo `http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php` and check what i returns

Comment: Now i add this two lines
    $info=curl_getinfo($handler);
    echo " $info"; 
And it returns "Array"

Comment: do a `var_dump($response);` or `var_dump($info);`. And for the rest: go follow a few PHP tutorials since you don't seem to have a clue as to what you're doing.

Comment: (¬_¬) ... well you are right I dont have so much idea, I copied this code from a  blog I run it thinking "oh maybe this could work for learn how to send post parameters to a web service" because I tried  a lot of codes thats why I'm asking you guys if you do know whats is wrong with the code. I'm here because I want to learn.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to learn *entire concepts*. It is a place for finding answers to short, concrete, problems. Your problem is you're missing the entire concept ;-)

Comment: All right u_u ... can you suggest me please a blog or something where I can find documentation  about how to use curl for what I'm looking for

Comment: How about starting in the most obvious place: [the manual](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)? Or, let's go nuts, and use a [searchengine](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+curl+tutorial)!

Comment: o_o ... what is wrong with you ??? I'm just trying to do a homework and I search of course but I don't found a code that works for an authentication via post

Comment: The point of homework is that *you* do it, not us. *You* need to learn from your homework, not *us*. If we just present you "the answer", what have you learned? All you do then is copy/paste it and before we know it we're stuck with another intern that doesn't know the first thing about development. Pointing you to the manual and directing you (with keywords) to a searchengine is the best thing that could've happened to you. Mark my words. In a few years you'll thank me. It'll make you selfsufficient.

Comment: And by the way; the code you posted may *actually* work perfectly fine. Your problem is you're missing the big picture and you need to learn how to process the "outcome" (`$response`) of the curl-request.

Comment: I'm not trying that you guys make my homework, I just asked  what was missing or wrong with the code that was actually what you told me in your last answer ... Thanks Roblll :D